How to make the Calendar field in an admin list filter form work well
The calendar field almost works in a standard joomla admin list filter form, but not quite.  The problem is that if the input is submitted on change, it submits the form each time the year or month left and right buttons are clicked because the date in the input changes.
<field
        name="mydatefilter"
        type="calendar"
        label="Appt Start"
        hint="Appts Start Range"
        format="%Y-%m-%d"
        filter="none"
        class="js-select-submit-on-change"
    />

This has been raised and closed as an issue as "the calendar field is not designed to work in the admin list filter".
[https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/39365]
Other suggestions include clicking the search button or a custom button after setting the filters.
The best solution (I think) would be to be able to add an event listener to the calendar close event and submit the admin form on that if the calendar field value has changed.
In  /media/system/js/fields/calendar.js there is a hide function.
/** Method to hide the calendar. */
    JoomlaCalendar.prototype.hide = function () {
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", this._calKeyEvent, true);
        document.removeEventListener("keypress", this._calKeyEvent, true);
        document.removeEventListener("mousedown", this._documentClick, true);

        this.dropdownElement.classList.remove('open');
        this.dropdownElement.setAttribute('hidden', '');
        this.hidden = true;
    };

But without the calendar script raising an event how could an external script use this as a trigger to submit the admin form?
Here is a very rough improvement I'm already using - I placed this script under the form on the applicable edit tmpl. Basically it allows the explicit date clicks to submit the adminform (by checking if the calendar has closed after the value change) and thus avoids submitting on month and year nav.  It also adds a listener on the close button and submits on that.  It doesn't check if the calendar closed because the user clicked away which it probably should.
// assuming the filter field is called "abegin"

let filter_abegin = jQuery('#filter_abegin');
let filter_abegin_cal = false;
filter_abegin.change(function(){
    // the calendar has been built now so we can save the selector and add a listener on the close button.
    if(!filter_abegin_cal){
        filter_abegin_cal = filter_abegin.parent().parent().find('.js-calendar');
    filter_abegin_cal.find('.js-btn.btn-exit').click(function(){
        adminForm.submit();
    });
    }
    // wait a little to make sure the dropdown has gone.
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(!filter_abegin_cal.hasClass('open')){
            adminForm.submit();
        }
    }, 100);
});


Maybe a long term solution is to update ..\media\system\js\searchtools.js with a js-select-submit-on-lost-focus or something more relevant that can be used on the calendar field when it is closed.
